# How can I make a button fit a css grid container's cell?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have something like this:

```
<div class="content" >
  <div class="nested">
        <div class="one">something</div>
        <div class="two">something something</div>
        <div class="three">..</div>
        .....

        <div class="eight"><button class="buy_now_button">Buy Now!</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.buy_now_button
{
  place-self: center stretch;
}
```

I want to make the button in the eighth div stretch and fit itself in the cell it is contained. My code has no effect on the button and it just remains the top left of the cell. Would appreciate any help!

I have been following this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: what happen if you set width:100%?

Comment: Hey Alyssa It would really help people help you if you could provide a working jsfiddle/codepen/else with your challenge. Especially with visual challenges it really helps to find the part that is not working properly with a live demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I understand it right, but if you just want to stretch the button, use:

```
width: 100%;
```

```css
.content {
  background-color: green;
}

.nested {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50%;
}

.buy_now_button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" >
  <div class="nested">
        <div class="one">something</div>
        <div class="two">something something</div>
        <div class="three">..</div>
        <div class="eight"><button class="buy_now_button">Buy Now!</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

width:100% works but if button is not in a grid,it'l occupy 100% width of document.
So, it's better to write

```css
button {
  justify-self:stretch;/*width:100%;*/
}
```